# Missing View in Inspector Area in Xcode Version 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xcode13

I have Xcode version 13.3. After downloading Xcode 13, I can set the corner radius from the storyboard. This feature is given by Xcode it is not a custom function or IBinspectable. My old view with the features.

[image: Old Image]

But now this feature is not showing in Xcode. I have redownloaded Xcode but still, the same issue appears in The Xcode.

[image: New Image]

Can someone suggest to me what's wrong here?

Comment: You can achieve the same programmatically or make an IBDesignable class.

Comment: @Saurabh i know but the issue this feature was given by default in Xcode, But now it's not showing.

Comment: Right, so you can try using the older version of Xcode (lower than 13) if possible.

Comment: @Saurabh is it a bug or Is kind of setting i have to do in xcode preferences ?

Comment: Not sure, however, I need to manually add this capability wherever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is not provided by the default corner radius option if you wish you can add a corner radius from the storyboard you need to add an extension for UIView.

I am using Xcode 13.2.1, I have checked for the same in my Xcode, after adding Extension I am able to add a corner radius from the storyboard.